# Extend css file point of sale odoo 9

Tags: odoo, odoo-9

I want add new class referenc-tag to point of sale

In mycss.css I have:

```css
.referenc-tag {
    color: #FFF;
    background: #000;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}
```

In xml

```xml
<template id="assets" inherit_id="point_of_sale.assets">
    <xpath expr="." position="inside">
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="/pos_odoo/static/src/css/mycss.css"/>
    </xpath>
</template>
```

After add class to element and install module my element can't get style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example is correct, try clear cache and add to openerp.py xml

```
<template id="assets" name="pos_odoo assets" inherit_id="point_of_sale.assets">
        <xpath expr="." position="inside">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="/pos_odoo/static/src/css/mycss.css" />
        </xpath>
</template>
```

to openerp.py

'data':[
        'your xml'
    ],

Answer (score 2):

Your template in the xml should look like this:

```xml
<template id="assets_backend" name="pos_odoo assets" inherit_id="web.assets_backend">
        <xpath expr="." position="inside">
             <link rel="stylesheet" href="/pos_odoo/static/src/css/mycss.css"/>
        </xpath>
    </template>
```

After this you need to add class="referenc-tag" to your prefered xml file, form, tree or whatever, to have the new styles.

Don't forget to add all xml files to your openerp.py file.

Comment: well then whats the error log message or whats happening at all?

Comment: No error log in console, only my new class can't get style from css file.